# Append a list of arrays as column to pandas Data Frame with same column indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, append

I have a list of arrays (one-dimensional numpy array) (a_) and a list (l_) and want to have a DataFrame with them as its columns. They look like this:

```
a_: [array([381]), array([376]), array([402]), array([400])...]
l_: [1.5,2.34,4.22,...]
```

I can do it by:

> ```
> df_l = pd.DataFrame(l_)
> df_a = pd.DataFrame(a_)
> df = pd.concat([df_l, df_a], axis=1)
> ```

Is there a **shorter** way of doing it? I tried to use `pd.append`:

> ```
> df_l = pd.DataFrame(l_)
> df_l = df_l.append(a_)
> ```

However, because columns indices are both 0, it adds a_ to the end of the dataframe column, resulting in a single column. Is there something like this:

> `l_ = l_.append(a_).reset(columns)`

that set a new column index for the appended array? well, obviously this does not work!

the desired output is like:

> ```
>   0       0
> 0 1.50    381
> 1 2.34    376
> 2 4.22    402
> ```
>
> ...

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Very good example, easy to follow...working for me!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suggestion:

```
df_l = pd.DataFrame(l_) 
df_1['a_'] = pd.Series(a_list, index=df_1.index)
```

Example #1:

```
L = list(data)
A = list(data)
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(L) 
data_frame['A'] = pd.Series(A, index=data_frame.index)
```

Example #2 - Same Series length (create series and set index to the same as existing data frame):

```
In [33]: L = list(item for item in range(10))

In [34]: A = list(item for item in range(10,20))

In [35]: data_frame = pd.DataFrame(L,columns=['L'])

In [36]: data_frame['A'] = pd.Series(A, index=data_frame.index)

In [37]: print data_frame

   L   A
0  0  10
1  1  11
2  2  12
3  3  13
4  4  14
5  5  15
6  6  16
7  7  17
8  8  18
9  9  19
```

Example #3 - Different Series lengths (create series and let pandas handle index matching):

```
In [45]: not_same_length = list(item for item in range(50,55))

In [46]: data_frame['nsl'] = pd.Series(not_same_length)

In [47]: print data_frame

   L   A  nsl
0  0  10   50
1  1  11   51
2  2  12   52
3  3  13   53
4  4  14   54
5  5  15  NaN
6  6  16  NaN
7  7  17  NaN
8  8  18  NaN
9  9  19  NaN
```

Based on your comments, it looks like you want to join your list of lists.I'm assuming they are in list structure because `array()` is not a method in python. To do that you would do the following:

```
In [63]: A = [[381],[376], [402], [400]]

In [64]: A = [inner_item for item in A for inner_item in item]

In [65]: print A

[381, 376, 402, 400]
```

Then create the Series using the new array and follow the steps above to add to your data frame.

Comment: Thank you very much @kennes913, It works, but my array is like [array([381]), array([376])...], so your answer gives a column like [381], [376] ... How do I get rid of the brackets then?

Comment: I'm unclear what the issue is. Can you print the output?

Comment: Actually your answer works, but I think I had not explained my question well. I have updated it now. I have two lists, and the problem is with the a_ list which is a list of arrays (a_: [array([381]), array([376]), array([402]), array([400])...]), so the output using your answer is: [381], [376], [402],... while I want to get: 381, 376, 402 .... I hope I'm clear.

Comment: thank you, but no. I already have the solution which is to change both of the lists to data frames and then use `pd.concat`, as explained in the question. I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing that. Your answer is really useful but adds more lines to the code. Thank you for your time any way.